# Auto scroll list to last view position Android

Tags: android

I need to implement list view with auto scrollable feature, till last seen position in list means when I run that activity to second time then it should have to auto scroll till last seen position.

Is it possible in Android? I implemented my list by array adapter code below:

```
    setListAdapter(new QuestionsArrayAdapter(this, SUBJECT, AUTHOR, RESPONCES, DATETIME, NEWPOST, LOGOIMAGE));
```

QuestionArratAdapter class is:

```
      public class QuestionsArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {



      public QuestionsArrayAdapter(Context context, String[] questions,
        String[] author, String[] responces, String[] dateTime,
        String[] newPost, String[] logoImage) {
    super(context, R.layout.questionscreen, author);
    this.context = context;
    this.questions = questions;
    this.author = author;
    this.responces = responces;
    this.dateTime = dateTime;
    this.newPost = newPost;
    this.logoImage = logoImage;
    
      imageLoader=new ImageLoader(context.getApplicationContext());
      
    
}

  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    
    
    //System.out.println(s);

    //imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_preview);
    return rowView;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can save the last seen position while you leaving the activity by;

```
int position = yourListView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
```

Then, while coming for the second time to your activity, you can use the smooth scroll method of list view like this,

```
yourListView.smoothScrollToPosition(position);
```

You can get yourListView with the code `this.getListView()` in the case you are using a `ListActivity`

Comment: how to save my last view position for second time  use?

Comment: try implementing onScroll() listener for your list view, and save the position of list item from that listener.

Comment: or you can save the item position while you leaving the activity by the method *yourListView.getFirstVisiblePosition();*

Comment: I edited my answer to reflect these changes. Plz have a look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Use this property for `listview` when you open activity second time

```
public void smoothScrollToPosition (int position)
```

in code

```
listview.smoothScrollToPosition(pos)
```

look at this [Document for listview](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#smoothScrollToPosition%28int%29)

Comment: hello RAjaReddy..thanks for your responce..where should i paste this code, means on which method?

Comment: for list view, where you set adapter for list view..like this listview.smoothScrollToPosition(position);

Comment: how to save postion for next time use?

Comment: for your last position, when you came first time to this view just store last position form getview of adapter or size of adapter - 1 gives last position. using shared preferences you can save int values..

Comment: i  never make the object of list view as u can see in my code then how would i do   listview.smoothScrollToPosition(pos)

Comment: ok, are you using listActivity, in this case you can get size of adapter getAdapter.seze() by using this property. use this can achieve the requirement.

Comment: what would i do of size of adapter ? please can you code for me? please